# Rewrite dynamic url structure

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hi everyone im having some pages with the person names. And im looking to move them on a subfolder but somehow redirect the old page to the new one, so when a visitor check the old page to redirect them to the new one but i'd like to remove the id of the person from the url structure.

```
http://domain.com/john-p001/       -> http://domain.com/person/john/

http://domain.com/george-p002/     -> http://domain.com/person/george/
```

What i was doing in my current setup on .htaccess

```
## internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-p([0-9]+)\/$ person.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L,NC,QSA,NE]
```

Another question i have, will this redirect keep my Search engine rank on these pages?

Comment: How will you get id from `http://domain.com/person/john/`?

Comment: John can be unique in persons, so there will be only 1 id.

Comment: So `http://domain.com/person/john/` should be internally rewritten as `/person.php?name=john` ?

Comment: Exactly like that, maybe ill have this too &year=2015 but thats irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect old URLs to newer ones
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-p([0-9]+)/?$ /person/$1 [L,NC,R=302]

## internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^person/([\w-]+)/?$ person.php?name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the immediate response, something else before i test this out. Maybe after a few months i can remove the old to new url rule or should i keep this forever?

Comment: You can keep this old to new rule forever, no need to remove it. You never know who has bookmarked it.

Comment: You're right bookmarks and old links will need this rule, thanks a lot.